# Como fazer um redirecionamento via .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess

Eu gostaria de redirecionar 15 a 20 `urls` estáticas de um site para outra url, tipo:

`http://meusite.com.br/home1.html` para `http://novosite.com.br`
`http://meusite.com.br/home2.html` para `http://novosite.com.br`
`http://meusite.com.br/home3.html` para `http://novosite.com.br`
`http://meusite.com.br/home4.html` para `http://novosite.com.br`
`http://meusite.com.br/home5.html` para `http://novosite.com.br`

Como eu posso fazer isso com .htaccess?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você deve usar a flag `[R=301]` ou `[R=302]` apenas pra indicar o tipo de direcionamento.

No caso se for 301 é um redirecionamento permanente, se 302 então é redirecionamento temporário.

No site `meusite.com.br` você deve criar na pasta raiz um .htaccess com o seguinte conteudo:

```apacheconf
RewriteRule ^home1\.html$ http://novosite.com.br [R=301]
RewriteRule ^home2\.html$ http://novosite.com.br [R=301]
RewriteRule ^home3\.html$ http://novosite.com.br [R=301]
RewriteRule ^home4\.html$ http://novosite.com.br [R=301]
RewriteRule ^home5\.html$ http://novosite.com.br [R=301]
RewriteRule ^home6\.html$ http://novosite.com.br [R=301]
```

Se os paths das urls no novo site forem iguais a do antigo, você deve fazer assim:

```apacheconf
RewriteRule ^home1\.html$ http://novosite.com.br/$0 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^home2\.html$ http://novosite.com.br/$0 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^home3\.html$ http://novosite.com.br/$0 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^home4\.html$ http://novosite.com.br/$0 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^home5\.html$ http://novosite.com.br/$0 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^home6\.html$ http://novosite.com.br/$0 [R=301]
```

O `$0` já identifica o path da url por causa do regex

Se todas urls tem este padrão home1.html á home20.html, você pode simplificar para:

```apacheconf
RewriteRule ^home(\d+)\.html$ http://novosite.com.br/$0 [R=301]
```

o `\d+` representa "qualquer numero", então ele vai reconhecer home1.html ou home10001.html por exemplo.

Você pode trocar `[R=301]` por `[R=302]` acaso o redirecionamento seja temporário e no futuro volte a ser o antigo site.

Note que você também pode querer usar a flag `[QSA]` acaso queira direcionar urls com querystring, por exemplo se acessar `meusite.com.br/home1.html?foo=a` ele deverá redirecionar para `novosite.com.br/home1.html` com o .htaccess

Mas se usar a flag `[QSA]` então o redirecionamento ficará assim `novosite.com.br/home1.html?foo=a`

Para isto use assim:

```apacheconf
RewriteRule ^home(\d+)\.html$ http://novosite.com.br/$0 [QSA,R=301]
```