# O que significam RewriteCond e RewriteRule em um arquivo .htaccess?

Tags: apache, htaccess

Sei que são utilizados para inúmeros fins, seja redirecionamento interno ou externo, porém nunca entendi o que cada um faz, sempre que preciso de algo tenho que recorrer à scripts prontos pois não sei fazer.

Por exemplo, nesse código:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

Ele redireciona tudo para minha index e o que estiver depois como parâmetro, mas o que significaria as linhas `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` e `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## RewriteCond

Voce deve usar a diretiva [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) para adicionar condições para aplicar ou não o redirecionamento.

Por exemplo:

```htaccess
# Redirect when we have a single parameter
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?mod=$1
```

Neste caso, as flags `!-f` e `!-d` estão determinando que o redirect só ocorrera **se não existir arquivo ou pasta com a url correspondente**.

### Sintaxe

A sintaxe do comando é:

```htaccess
RewriteCond TestString CondPattern
```

Onde `CondPattern` é uma *REGEXP* compatível com perl, com alguns acréscimos.

Voce pode prefixar o pattern com `!` para inverter seu efeito. Há algumas variações que permitem usar o `CondPattern` sem *REGEXP* também:

```htaccess
'<CondPattern'
'>CondPattern'
'=CondPattern'
```

Essas últimas três tratam a `CondPattern` literalmente como string, e comparam respectivamente a `TestString` com o valor literal da `CondPattern`

**Veja mais algumas condições:**

- `-d` Pega o o resultado da `TestString` e verifica se é um diretório existente
- `-f` Pega o o resultado da `TestString` e verifica se é um arquivo existente
- `-s` Faz o mesmo que o `-f`, mas só considera arquivos não-vazios
- `-l` Verifica se o resultado da `TestString` é caminho para um link simbólico
- `-x` Verifica se o resultado da `TestString` é um caminho com permissão +x
- `-F` Equivale ao `-f`, mas faz um teste pra ver se o arquivo é realmente acessível pelo Apache. Isso implica em fazer uma requisição interna extra no teste, cuidado com uso em excesso.
- `-U` Mesmo que o `-F`, mas testa por URL e não Path

Todos estes testes podem ser negados com uma `!` no início.

### Variáveis

Tanto para o RewriteCond quanto para o RewriteRule, há algumas variáveis pré-populadas que podem ser usadas delimitadas com `%{  }`. Veja algumas das mais comuns:

- `REMOTE_ADDR` é o IP do `host` remoto
- `REQUEST_FILENAME` é o caminho completo do arquivo que atende ao request original, tomando por base o *filesystem* da máquina, e não relativo à hospedagem. Cuidado: caso seja usado em VirtualHost, tem o mesmo efeito que o `REQUEST_URI`.
- `REQUEST_SCHEME` retorna usualmente `http` ou `https`, dependendo da conexão.
- `REQUEST_URI` é uma das variáveis mais usadas. É a que tem o caminho da requisição, como por exemplo `index.html`. Ela **não** inclui a *query*. Tudo que vem da `?` em diante é retornado em QUERY_STRING.
- `THE_REQUEST` é a linha completa do request, como por exemplo `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`. Não inclui os *headers* e nao é "escapada", diferentemente das outras variáveis.

## RewriteRule

A diretiva RewriteRule faz a reescrita do URL, e se ocorrer mais de uma vez, é aplicada na ordem sequencial do arquivo.

### Sintaxe

```htaccess
 RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]
```

Pattern é basicamenteis uma RegEx compatível com Perl. Na primeira ocorrência, é aplicada a RegEx ao URL depois de decodificado (`%`). Os seguintes RegExes são aplicados à saida do Rewrite anterior.

Substitution é uma string que pode ser mesclada com resultados (grupos) extraídos da RegEx, e também variáveis delimitada por `%{   }` conforme exemplificado acima.

### Flags

Seguem algumas das flags mais comuns:

- `L` considera este sendo o último Rewrite, não aplicando mais nenhuma regra que modifique o URL
- `R=code` faz um redirect com o código indicado (ex: 301, 302)
- `NC` (No-case) faz comparações ignorando maiúsculas e minúsculas
- `N` refaz a cadeia de modificações, começando pela primeira novamente
- `QSA`(query string append) depois das modificações feitas, aplica a *query string* original ao final da linha (em outras palavras, preserva o que tinha depois da ? no URI original)
- `CO` seta um *cookie* no formato `CO=NAME:VAL:domain[:lifetime[:path[:secure[:httponly]]]]`

A descrição completa das flags se encontra na [documentação](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

### Exemplo:

```htaccess
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(([a-z0-9_]+.)?exemplo.com.br)$ [NC]  
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

No exemplo acima estamos verificando se o domínio está com www, e removendo o mesmo na linha seguinte, mantendo o resto do URL.

A flag R=301 determina que seja um redirect permanente, e o L indica que é a última operação desta cadeia. NC indica que a comparação ignorará maiúsculas e minúsculas, e o QSA fará com que se houver *query string* (`?nome=valor&...`), esta seja conservada no redirect.

**Descrevendo o exemplo posto na pergunta**

- `RewriteEngine On`
  Ativa o módulo Rewrite, que faz a reescrita de URL.
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
  Determina que o rewrite só se aplicará se nao (`!`) existir um arquivo (`-f`) com aquele nome
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
  Determina que o rewrite só se aplicará se nao (`!`) existir um diretório (`-d`) com aquele nome
- `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC]`
  Redireciona o usuário para index.php?params=$1 para qualquer URL entrado.
  Aqui, o $1 é o 1º grupo da RegEx, determinado pelos `( )`s na captura.
  O NC neste caso não serve para nada, nem precisaria estar no Rewrite.

Comment: O q seria um redirect permanente determinada pela flag R=301?

Comment: Você usa 301 quando é coisa definitiva, ou 302 quando é um redirecionamento temporário. normalmente nao precisa especificar isso manualmente.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78445/70

Answer (score 8):

São diretivas para o módulo ***MOD_REWRITE***.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/pt-br/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Como o proprio manual do httpd diz:

**RewriteCond**: A diretiva *RewriteCond* define uma condição para uma regra. Uma ou mais *RewriteCond* podem preceder uma *diretiva* *RewriteRule*. A regra a seguir é então utilizada somente se tanto o estado atual da URI corresponde ao seu padrão, e se essas condições foram atendidas.

**RewriteRule**: A directiva *RewriteRule* é o verdadeiro carro-chefe da reescrita. A diretiva pode ocorrer mais de uma vez, com cada instância definindo uma única regra de reescrita. A ordem em que estas regras são definidas é importante - esta é a ordem em que elas serão aplicadas em tempo de execução.

Usa-se uma expressão regular *perl compatível*. Na primeira *RewriteRule* é aplicado à (% -decoded) URL da requisição; padrões subsequentes são aplicados à saída da última regra RewriteRule que combine.

No exemplo

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

`RewriteEngine On` Informa para ativar o módulo de Reescrita

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` Informa que será criado uma condição a ser aplicado ao nome do arquivo requisitado. A exclamação é o sinal de negação e **-f** pede para verificar a existência de um arquivo físico. Portanto a tradução é

```
CONDIÇÃO = SE ARQUIVO_REQUISITADO NÃO EXISTE FISICAMENTE
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` Informa que será criado uma condição a ser aplicado ao nome do arquivo requisitado. Novamente, a exclamação indica negação e **-d** pede para checar existência de um diretório fisicamente. Portanto a tradução é:

```
CONDIÇÃO = SE ARQUIVO_REQUISITADO NÃO EXISTE COMO DIRETÓRIO FISICAMENTE
```

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC]` Informa que será aplicado uma regra de reescrita. **^(.*)$** Indica para armazenar em uma variável toda a requisição da URL (Circunflexo indica inicio e Cifrão indica fim). *index.php?params=$1* Indica para substituir a requisição, redirecionando o fluxo para index.php e colocando-a inteiramente como um parametro de params. * [NC]* São flags. No caso indica para não ser sensivel a maiusculas ou minusculas (NON-CASE).

Mais sobre [flags aqui](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/pt-br/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags)

Comment: Explicação simples e direta. Finalmente consegui entender.