# Duvida em .htacess

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite

Galera, eu faço estágio numa empresa de desenvolvimento web e tals e a pouco tempo tivemos um problema em redirecionamento da pagina.

Na empresa usamos para esse projeto Php MVC (Nunca cheguei a me aprofundar em Php) e um arquivo .htacess que também nunca havia visto.

Então sobre esse arquivo, podem me explicar o que este codigo está fazendo?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (\.php)$

#RewriteBase /projetos/c/*****/dev/acompanhamentoobra/
RewriteBase /acompanhamentoobra/

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Por favor, se souberem de um material que ensine um pouco sobre esse tipo de arquivo podem me passar também, dei uma breve procurada mas nada que fosse significativo para resolver o problema.

Comment: Que problema? você perguntou só que ele faz.

Comment: Este post fala sobre o `RewriteCond` http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102722/11404

Comment: Redirecionamento, ao tentar entrar em um site que está no FTP ele reconhece porém é redirecionado para o HOME. Como não sei muito sobre esses tipos de arquivos estou indo de baixo para cima, e querendo saber se o problema pode ser neste arquivo que passei

Comment: O link que o @JcSaint mandou já deu pra clarear alguma coisa, aqueles !-d e !-f verificam se o diretório e arquivo existem, provavelmente eles não estão sendo reconhecidos e então redireciona para a index, talvez ...

Comment: Tente isso: [http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis).

Comment: Ou isso: [http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resumidamente a regra de reescrita de URL diz que todas as requisições devem ir para o arquivo index.php receber as requisições pelo parâmetro `path`.

Nesse arquivo index.php terá algo como `$_GET['path']` ou pode estar dentro de uma função e não visível no indesx.php.

Essas regras serão aplicadas para a pasta `/acompanhamentoobra/` que está definida como base.

As linhas com `-f`, `-d` e `-l` é para ignorar a regra caso seja acessado um arquivo, um diretório ou link simbólico existente, respectivamente.

O trecho `(\.php)$` é para desviar de arquivos .php nessa pasta e entrar na condição de reescrita.

obs:
Mas não confunda ou misture as coisas. PHP, MVC e htccess são distintos um do outro. Na pergunta em si não tem nada de MVC ou PHP.

O htaccess é parte do módulo `mod_rewrite` do Apache.

Comment: Então, até mesmo em java por exemplo podemos utilizar esse .htacess? Já que é uma "configuração" do servidor, basta usar o apache e ele já funcionaria?

Comment: java? vc se refere ao java ou javascript? ou  jsp?

Comment: Neste caso jsp, digo, como é uma configuração do apache pouco importa a linguagem em que está sendo desenvolvido é isso?

Comment: Terá algumas variações. Normalmente o JSP roda sob o Tomcat também do Apache Group. Mas no geral tudo funciona igual ao Apache httpd

Comment: Ok Daniel, obrigado! Vou trabalhar em cima disso agora e tentar ver qual é o problema, muito provavelmente está nesse arquivo.