# Como usar o Rewrite para incluir sub-diretorio e slug?

Tags: htaccess, apache

Edição: Refiz as informações com base nas respostas e dúvidas dos colaboradores.

**urls internas nos menus:**
a href="/cursos/matem/?slug=algebra-linear">Matemática Algebra
a href="/cursos/ciencias/?slug=estrutura-molecular">Ciências Estruturas
a href="/cursos/ingles/?slug=basico-para-viagens">Ingles Básico

**Preciso que no navegador apareça:**
site.com/cursos/matem/algebra-linear
site.com/cursos/ciencias/estrutura-molecular
site.com/cursos/ingles/basico-para-viagens

**Utilizei o Rewrite da resposta edição 2 do Marcelo Rafael** (ver abaixo)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.png)|(\.css)|(\.jpg)|(\.gif)|(\.mp4)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(videos/)|(duv/)$
RewriteRule "^cursos\/(.+)\/(.+)" "http://site.com/cursos/$1/?slug=$2" [R]
```

**Resultados:**
a url: href="/cursos/matem/algebra-linear">

**No navegador aparece**
site.com/cursos/matem/?slug=algebra-linear

Não está havendo uma inversão no Rewrite?

Nos 2 casos as páginas linkadas abrem normalmente. E demais diretórios do site estão OK.

```
Estrutura do site: 
.htacess
index.php
css/
js/
funções/
forum/
duvidas/
exames/
cursos/
    matem/index.php (os subdiretorios são os tipos de cursos)
        /imgs/
        /duv/
        /videos/
        pag1 <= slug
        pag2 <= slug
    ciencias/index.php
        /imgs/
        /duv/
        /videos/
        pag1 <= slug
        pag2 <= slug
    (são dezenas de cursos)
```

Peço desculpas se não usei os termos técnicos corretos e agradeço toda ajuda e sugestão

**meu htaccess completo**

```
##### LOCAWEB - NAO REMOVER #####
AddHandler php71-script .php
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/site/
##### LOCAWEB - NAO REMOVER #####

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.png)|(\.css)|(\.jpg)|(\.gif)|(\.mp4)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(videos/)|(duv/)$
RewriteRule "^cursos\/(.+)\/(.+)" "http://site.com/cursos/$1/?slug=$2" [R]

RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /erros-4xx.php
ErrorDocument 500 /erros-4xx.php
ErrorDocument 403 /erros-4xx.php
ErrorDocument 400 /erros-4xx.php

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-eruby
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch ^HMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
FileETag None
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge"
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|gif|png|jpeg|pdf|xml|oga|ogg|m4a|ogv|mp4|m4v|webm|svg|svgz|eot|ttf|otf|woff|ico|webp|appcache|manifest|htc|crx|oex|xpi|safariextz|vcf)$" >
Header unset X-UA-Compatible
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Até já apaguei tudo e só deixei o Rewrite, mas continua igual.
Onde está errado? É um desafio para todos.

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema é que voce não está colocando a segunda parte do `RewriteRule` ou seja, o target, do site que voce quer ir, e também coloque essa Expressão regular.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
#este é meu diretorio de testes, ex: http://localhost/stackoverflow/rewrite/
RewriteBase /stackoverflow/rewrite/   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule "^cursos\/(.+)\/(.+)" "http://site.com/cursos/$1/?slug=$2" [R]
```

Aqui está a expressão regular

https://regex101.com/r/DcYGkZ/1

#### Edição

Você disse que as imagens não estão aparecendo, coloque `RewriteCond` para verificar se é um arquivo e se um diretório.

Voce pode ver o funcionamento de `RewriteCond` aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102731/65558

#### 2* Edição

Meu ambiente

```
http://localhost/stackoverflow/rewrite/
/.htaccess
/index.php
/cursos
    /assets
        /style.css
        /img.png
    /matem
        /index.php
```

Meu **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /stackoverflow/rewrite/

#aqui verifica se tem .png .css e .jpg no final da requisição
#se tiver um dos, cancela o RewriteRule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.png)|(\.css)|(\.jpg)$

RewriteRule "^cursos\/(.+)\/(.+)" "http://localhost/stackoverflow/rewrite/cursos/$1/?slug=$2" [R]
```

Meu **/cursos/matem/index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Matem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <img src="../assets/img.png">
</body>
</html>
```

É isso que eu posso fazer para te ajudar, seus problemas com `.img` estão vagos para mim, não tem como saber o que está acontecendo exatamente.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73365/discussion-on-answer-by-marcelo-rafael-como-usar-o-rewrite-para-incluir-sub-dire)

Comment: @Maniero por que ?

Comment: Porque aqui não é um fórum, os comentários não são para discussões, para solução de problema de forma interativa. Sempre que fica longo é porque tem algo errado (pergunta ou resposta são ruins e não está ajudando) e o sistema sinaliza.

Comment: @Maniero entendido, vlw

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira bem simples seria:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?req=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
Options -Indexes
```

index.php

```
<?php $_GET['req'] = isset($_GET['req']) ? str_replace( "..", "", $_GET['req'] ) : ""; ?>
```

Comment: Coloquei seu rewrite mas ao entrar no site perdeu o css. o que pode ter ocorrido? é php7.1, se ajudar.

Comment: ah sim, deixar os diretorios dos seus assets fora da regas, ex:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/arquivos/

obs: eu dei update no meu comentario

Comment: Coloquei o css na 2ªlinha e funcionou. Mas as imagens estão distribuidas em cada tipo de curso e fica quase impossível relacionar tudo no RewriteCond. Não existe um comando geral como: "Desconsiderar Regra para imgs e outros". Motivo:tenho tb outros diretórios que não devem ser afetados. Obrigado

Comment: tem sim,

os:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d


atualizei no meu comentário

Comment: Coloquei o seu rewrite agora e o site perdeu o css. Será que tem algo interferindo? devo postar o .htaccess completo para vc analisar?

Comment: Refiz o texto da pergunta e inclui a estrutura do site para ajudar nas análises.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolvi da seguinte maneira:**

No .htaccess do index principal

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

**E nas pastas (sub-diretórios)**

Em cada pasta criei um .htaccess com o Rewrite acima

E em cada **index.php** (das pastas) inclui:

```
<base href="http://meusite.com/pasta-xx/">
```

Funciona perfeitamente.