# Conflito em Arquivo .Htacess

Tags: regex, htaccess

No htacess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/$ blog/assuntos.php?disciplina=$1
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/(.*)$ blog/pagina.php?disciplina=$1&assunto=$2
```

As urls:

```
http://localhost/teste.com/blog/portugues/
http://localhost/teste.com/blog/geografia/mundo
```

Nas páginas:

```
$disciplina=$_GET['disciplina'];
$assunto=$_GET['assunto'];
```

Problema:

Com essas regras consigo pegar a segunda url mas a primeira não, a primeira tá retornando **assuntos.php** no `$_GET['assunto'];`. Queria que o primeiro retornasse no `$_GET['disciplina'];`.

Quando eu retiro uma das regras a outra funciona perfeitamente, mas com as duas dá conflito. Alguém sabe o que pode está ocorrendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque `[L]` no final de cada `RewriteRule` que forem de fato "regras" diferentes, como é o caso, também é preciso notar que a expressão regular com `(.*)` vai pegar qualquer coisa, é como um "curinga" na regex, então você tem que dizer para a regex o que ele tem que desconsiderar, e no caso o que faltou foi desconsiderar as barras `/`

Resumindo, ao invés disto `(.*)` o certo seria isto `([^/]+)`, o `[^/]` casa com qualquer coisa que não for barra, o sinal `+` indica que é para pegar até encontrar a próxima "correspondência", então deveria ficar assim:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/$ blog/assuntos.php?disciplina=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ blog/pagina.php?disciplina=$1&assunto=$2 [L]
```

Para resumir, quando fazia isso `^blog/(.*)/$`, ele iria aceitar qualquer coisa, como:

```
/blog/foo
/blog/foo/bar
/blog/foo/bar/baz
/blog/sobre/etc
```

E mesmo que a primeria regra fosse ignorada, ainda sim a segunda falharia, porque iria aceitar qualquer coisa também, incluindo outras barras no meio `/`, sendo o minimo de duas barras dentro da expressão.

Aproveite para aprender o básico de .htaccess para reescritas:

- [O que significam RewriteCond e RewriteRule em um arquivo .htaccess?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102722/3635)

Muitas pessoas geralmente vivem de copiar códigos por ai sem entender o porque, entender os princípios básicos vai lhe poupar de muita dor de cabeça

Comment: Perfeito. Só o [L] já funcionou ,não sabia disso. Vou acertar o restante também pra ficar mais certinho. Valeu!!!

Comment: @Rod provavelmente funcionaria mesmo com o `[L]` porque em ordem de interpretação o proprio módulo deve priorizar a regra mais aproximada da URL atual, mas o problema é que um usuário escrever URLs com diversas barras (ao menos teoricamente ele casaria a regex)

Comment: @Rod Aproveite para aprender o básico de .htaccess para reescritas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102722/3635 Muitas pessoas geralmente vivem de copiar códigos por ai sem entender o porque, entender os princípios básicos vai lhe poupar de muita dor de cabeça

Comment: Vou dar uma lida, comprei livro, curso, mas é bem dificil regex. Agora mesmo estou tentando colocar um opcional /? no fim de cada url e não vai. Ô troço enjoado. rs

Comment: @Rod regex use o básico por enquanto, mas aprender o mod_rewrite do Apache (.htaccess) que é fundamental para evita alguns problemas :)