# Mesclagem de .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

estou procurando entender um pouco sobre o arquivo .htaccess mas não consigo fazer a mesclagem de duas regras.

Essa é a qual utilizo para o slim framework.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

E essa é a nova que gostaria de adicionar após esta:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Mas quando coloco uma seguida da outra o servidor estoura um erro. 
Também já tentei desta forma, mas assim a primeira regra para de funcionar...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Alguém teria alguma sugestão?

Comment: Leia as duas respostas dessa pergunta [O que significam RewriteCond e RewriteRule em um arquivo .htaccess?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102722/o-que-significam-rewritecond-e-rewriterule-em-um-arquivo-htaccess) que vão lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o link da pergunta que o Augusto Vasques postou aqui, consegui solucionar meu problema da seguinte forma:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Coloquei a regra de forçar o HTTPS abaixo da primeira e retirei a flag [L] da primeira regra também, assim ele continua considerando as abaixos.