# Como impedir que uma página específica seja redirecionada para https sem usar php?

Tags: htaccess, http, https, url-rewrite

Olá. Preciso evitar redirecionar uma página de meu site para https, mas não queria usar php, nem java, nem outra linguagem de programação.

Gostaria de usar o **.htaccess**

Em meu site, eu usei a regra abaixo no .htaccess para redirecionar todas as páginas do site para HTTPS.

```
# Forçando https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Funciona perfeitamente!
Porém existem páginas específicas que preciso que fiquem em HTTP, pois elas exibem conteúdos externos via iframe que vem em HTTP, e HTTP não é exibido dentro de HTTPS.

Eu tentei, adicionar ao fim da url o código **-no_ssl**

E adicionei o trecho abaixo no htaccess para que o ssl não fosse aplicado em urls que terminassem com **-no_ssl**

```
RewriteCond ^(.*)$ ([^-]|-[^n]|-n[^o]|-no[^_]|-no_[^s]|-no_s[^s]|-no_ss[^l])$
```

De modo que o código completo ficou assim:

```
# Forçando https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond ^(.*)$ ([^-]|-[^n]|-n[^o]|-no[^_]|-no_[^s]|-no_s[^s]|-no_ss[^l])$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Assim esperava que a página **meudominio.com/contato-no_ssl** não fosse redirecionada pra https.
Mas não funciona.

Onde eu posso estar errando?

Comment: Porque bloquearam minha pergunta, existem outras perguntas aqui sobre .htaccess. Qual o problema da minha? o que ela tem diferente desta aqui? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102722/o-que-significam-rewritecond-e-rewriterule-em-um-arquivo-htaccess#

Comment: Realmente, a questão enquadra-se perfeitamente neste fórum.

Comment: Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço, ou se tiver alguma forma de questionar esse bloqueio, esperava mais da plataforma. Qualquer um pode chegar e sair fechando perguntas só porque deu na telha e não tem como recorrer a outros usuários. muito estranho.